# NoSQL Manager cannot connect on SSH after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 (new OpenSSH server version)

Tags: nosql-manager

[NoSQL manager](http://www.mongodbmanager.com/) connected to Ubuntu 14.04's default OpenSSH Server without problems, but when I installed Ubuntu 16.04's new version of OpenSSH Server, I got this error at the client:

```
Testing connection...
An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
```

And this error at the server `/var/log/auth.log`

```
sshd[2212]: fatal: mm_answer_moduli: bad parameters: 2048 2048 1024
```

What can I do to make my older ssh client work with the new version of OpenSSH?

Answer (score 1):

this issue has been fixed in the version 3.7.0.5 of NoSQL Manager for MongoDB.
Currently embedded SSH tunneling supports OpenSSH server on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently OpenSSH Server removed support for the key algorithm `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`, and this caused the error.

The solution is to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add the line

```
# Added to make OpenSSH Server compatible with older SSH client - NoSQL manager
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Reference another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38231876/404699